# How to change background color of active tab in Bootstrap without affecting other active classes

Tags: css, bootstrap-4

I am using Bootstrap and I have this list:
[image]

Now, this is blue when it's active, I want to change that to green or something.

This is code:

```
<a class="list-group-item list-group-item-action active" id="list-home-list" data-toggle="list" href="#list-home" role="tab" aria-controls="home">v1.0.0</a>
```

That is the single item from the picture.

When I try to change "active" class it changes all of my other components and I don't want that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe the class you are targeting is not the correct one, try this. If you share you full code maybe we can see if theres any other issue.

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<style>
  .list-group-item.active {
  background-color: green;
  border-color: green;
}
</style>
<ul class="list-group">
  <li class="list-group-item active">Cras justo odio</li>
  <li class="list-group-item">Dapibus ac facilisis in</li>
  <li class="list-group-item">Morbi leo risus</li>
  <li class="list-group-item">Porta ac consectetur ac</li>
  <li class="list-group-item">Vestibulum at eros</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: That is correct, I will make it as Correct Answer in 8 mins!

Comment: Glad to be of help!